# creating a switch when checkbox is checked

Tags: android, checkbox

so i am trying to get it to either disable or enable the bool as seen below, when the user checks a checkbox, in my apps UI

```
/** called when the user clicks the enable checkbox field for enabling Subtraction Problems **/
public void BoolSubProb(View view) {
    if(SubProb = false) {
        SubProb = true;
    }
    else if(SubProb = true) {
        SubProb = false;
    }
}
```

but i cant seem to get it where it'll only do either enable the bool if its false or disable the bool when its true, when the user has checked the checkbox.
it just goes through the loop, and ends up becoming false again.

Comment: you probably mean `(SubProb ==true)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get an instance of your checkbox which should be defined in XML. Then, add a OnCheckedChangeListener to it.

Example code:

```
CheckBox mCheckbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yourCheckboxInXML);
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            //do something if it's checked
        } else {
            //do something if it's not checked
        }
    }
});
```

Also, a word of advice when comparing boolean values: Don't use a single equal sign...use double.

```
//Incorrect
if (myBoolean = true)

//Correct
if (myBoolean == true)
```

Edit: If you're using a Fragment, make sure you call getView() before the findViewById() method call.

Code:

```
CheckBox mCheckbox = (CheckBox) getView().findViewById(R.id.yourCheckboxInXML);
mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {
        if (b) {
            //do something if it's checked
        } else {
            //do something if it's not checked
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: theres a problem, i tried to implement your code and it says its unable to resolve symbol ".OnCheckedChangeListener" and for some reason it is unable to resolve method getView()

Comment: @connormurry are you using a fragment? getView() is ONLY for if you're using a fragment. If you're using an activity, refer to the first section of my answer.

Comment: yes im using an activity. my original problem i stated in my last comment still exists minus the getView() problem

Comment: Have you imported the CheckBox and CompundButton classes?

Comment: See my updated version of your Gist: https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Quebe/0c3ef8fb4e5434190263

Let me know if there are any more issues. I want to resolve this!!

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spizer.mizer2/com.spizer.mizer2.DifficultyMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Are you inflating the view that has the checkboxes in it?

Comment: My bad...I put the code in the wrong class. Updated: https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Quebe/0c3ef8fb4e5434190263

Comment: okay so the changes you made did not work, they do how ever work the original way you had it in the difficultymenu.java class

Comment: Welp! Whatever works right?! Glad you got it working. You can find me on G+ if you need more help.

Comment: one of the problems that i am having is when the thing tries to convert childposition from listdataheader it gives an indes error

Comment: It's against StackOverflows rules to chat in the comments section. Message me on Hangouts and I can help you more.

Comment: my original error still comes up : 09-20 14:56:22.973  10026-10026/com.spizer.mizer2 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.spizer.mizer2, PID: 10026
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spizer.mizer2/com.spizer.mizer2.DifficultyMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: PM me on Hangouts...I can better help you that way.

Comment: here try referring to this, i cant quite understand how to interpret it but maybe you can : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html

Comment: how can i reach you on hangouts

Comment: https://www.google.com/+AndrewQuebe If you have Hangouts on your device, start a new message and type in my name. Profile picture is the same as the one you see here.